# How to get line numbers with its text if keyword found

Tags: html, arrays

I have a HTML form
Where it takes the user input in text box like Discover then from Textarea box it will print
line number with Text

**Html code :**

```
<div>search</div>
<input type="text" id="needle" value="throw">
<div>this text</div>
<textarea id="haystack">Twenty years from now
you will be more disappointed 
by the things that you didn't 
do than by the ones you did do, 
so throw off the bowlines, 
sail away from safe harbor, 
catch the trade winds in your 
sails. Explore, Dream, Discover. 
    —Mark Twain
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick="searchText()"> <br><br>
<div>results</div>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

**Javascript :**

```
function searchText(){
// If you want to find the line number for a specific match you need to know it index
    function lineNumberByIndex(index,string){
        // RegExp
        var line = 0,
            match,
            re = /(^)[\S\s]/gm;
        while (match = re.exec(string)) {
            if(match.index > index)
                break;
            line++;
        }
        return line;
    }
    // if you want to find the first index of a match
    function lineNumber(needle,haystack){
        return lineNumberByIndex(haystack.indexOf(needle),haystack);
    }
    // if you want an array of matches
    function lineNumbers(needle,haystack){
        if(needle !== ""){
            var i = 0,a=[],index=-1;
            while((index=haystack.indexOf(needle, index+1)) != -1){
                a.push(lineNumberByIndex(index,haystack));
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
    function update(){
        var needle = $('#needle').val();
        var haystack = $('#haystack').val();
        var output = $("#output").val();
        var nums = lineNumbers(needle,haystack);
        var s = "\"" + needle + "\" is on lines " + nums.join(',') + "\n";
        if(nums.length)
            $("#output").val(s + output);
        else
            $("#output").val("-\n" + output);
    }
    $("input,textarea.input").on("input",update);
    update()
}
```

**.css**

```
* {font:1em arial}
input {width:400px;;padding:5px}
textarea {width:400px;height:200px;padding:5px;}
```

I have to call by creating Button click but it prints abnormal text , if i remove the search text and re enter any other text on button click the text appears n number of times

How to write code which could search for text and print its line number and text

**Code taken from here :** http://jsfiddle.net/pcmxw37d/

Abnormal Output :

```
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
"harbor" is on lines 6
```

Comment: `.on("change keyup paste"` nonono just use `.on("input"`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  can you check question agaian the output appear abnormal I have added the .on("input" in my code

Comment: Wait, are you asking how many lines there are in total, or which lines a word appears in?

Comment: @Rojo   if i enter any word it should display its line number with entire line text ..if i clear content of textbox then result area should get cleared off

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler example (which works also for case insensitive):

```js
const EL_searchField  = document.querySelector("#searchField");
const EL_searchArea   = document.querySelector("#searchArea");
const EL_searchResult = document.querySelector("#searchResult");  
const EL_searchButton = document.querySelector("#searchButton");


const search = () => {
  const val = EL_searchField.value.trim(); // Does exactly what it says
  const txt = EL_searchArea.value.trim();  // Does exactly what it says
  // Split lines and get them all as <div> Strings into an Array by using .reduce()
  const result = txt.split(/\n/).reduce((arr, line, i) => {
    if (line.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase())) {
      arr.push(`<div class="flex"><i>Line ${i+1}:</i><span>${(line.replace(new RegExp(val, "ig"), "<b>$&</b>"))}</span></div>`);
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
  // If no txt or no val: use an empty String ""
  // else, join our array of <div>s into a single String of HTML <div>s  
  EL_searchResult.innerHTML = (!val || !txt) ? "" : result.join("");
};

EL_searchField.addEventListener("input", search);
EL_searchArea.addEventListener("input", search);
EL_searchButton.addEventListener("click", search);
search();
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif; }

.flex { display: flex; }
#searchArea { width: 400px; max-width: 50%; height: 160px; }
#searchResult div { gap: 10px; }
#searchResult i   { opacity: 0.5; white-space: nowrap;}
#searchResult b   { color: blue;}
```

```html
<label><input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Search text..."></label>
<button type="button" id="searchButton">SEARCH</button>

<div class="flex">
<textarea id="searchArea">Twenty years from now
you will be more disappointed 
by the things that you didn't 
do than by the ones you did do, 
so throw off the bowlines, 
sail away from safe harbor, 
catch the trade winds throw in your 
sails. Explore, Dream, Discover.
    —Mark Twain</textarea>
<div id="searchResult"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: => Thanks  bro will try to understand the code

Comment: @codeholic24 edited for a better example with word highlight

Comment: I wanted it on button click bro ... the above code is not on button click

Comment: @codeholic24 ... well, adding two lines of code should not be hard ;) edited. If you don't want the better UX remove also the line `EL_searchField.addEventListener("input", search);` obviously.

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan  Thanks basically the same thing was obtained from http://jsfiddle.net/pcmxw37d/  but  code does not contain any button everytime i need to reload to check and debug that's why i wanted it on button click .. now perfect code

Comment: @codeholic24 try to understand the code, see how the line I added `EL_searchButton.addEventListener("click", search);` is similar to the other ones? :)  Happy coding!

Comment: When i am trying to debug by inputing all values i can see  it does not display message like No Match content found if nothing is enter in textbox  and clicked on button ... can you add one checkin if nothing is entered and button click it should  display no match found or something like that

Comment: @codeholic24 see the ternary operator `? "" :` Have you tried to just for example do something like `? "No match found!" : ` Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator the `EL_searchResult.innerHTML = ` part should have been pretty obvious, the Ternary operator is just used instead of an `if / else` block.

Comment: I got it your script is reading line by line the entire text area .. where ever it is finding the keyword .. it is adding it to the array then EOF the result is been displayed ... Is it right what i said .. can you add description to your code as specially at point of function

Comment: @codeholic24 added comments. For more info about Array.reduce:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score -1):

You can get the text using `.textContent` and use `split('\n')` to get each line in an array. Then, get the length of the array. `.split('\n')` returns an extra string at the end, so you'll have to ignore that

```
document.querySelector('#haystack').textContent.split('\n')
```

You'll need to run that line in the event listener so that it always updates.

Comment: Can you modified the code and show me how to do that ...?

Comment: can you help me with this how to get details on button click  if textbox as some details